# Check if a database has a child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I do to check if a database has a child in firebase like this:

```
 if(UsuariosRef.child(User.getUid()) == null)
```

What I try to do is check if the child exists in the database and this gives me error when the child does not exist.

Thank you so much

Comment: What's wrong with that code? Please show a [mcve] of the problem

Comment: In your code example, what is UsuariosRef? A Firebase DatabaseReference?
Try to include a dump of your database structure as well. You can export as JSON from the Firebase console.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I will take into account the next time, for now my doubts were resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading data from Firebase is done by adding listeners to the relevant nodes of the database and receiving DataSnapshots. Usually an ongoing listener which can react to any changes, but you can also add a listener which does a single read.

In this case if you want to do a one-off check to see if a particular node exists, you could use:

```
usuariosRef.child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
            // node exists
        } else {
            // node doesn't exist
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```